# A value of type "const int*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int* const"

Tags: c++, constants, c++23

I have this code in c++ on vs 2022 community version.

```
import std;

int main()
{
    constexpr int x = 10;
    constexpr int* p = &x;
    
    
}
```

I am not allowed to assign the address of x to p because of this: A value of type "const int*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int* const". So I understand that `&x` means `const int*` and `p` is  `int* const`. Why so? I think `p` is `pointer to const int`. It seems `constexpr` applies to `p` and not to `int`. Could you clarify?

Comment: You need to add `static` when defining `x`. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vP9M9G9o1) This is explained here. [constexpr int* ptr =&i compiles in msvc but not with clang and gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74080638/constexpr-int-ptr-i-compiles-in-msvc-but-not-with-clang-and-gcc/).

Comment: @user12002570: That is also a problem, but it's not the problem that the question asks about (pay attention to the title).

Comment: @ntos Even though you put your error message in the title, that does not excuse you from *also* putting it in the question body.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, there are 2  problems with the code. One explained in the dupe and one in the answer here.

Comment: That's... not how dupe closures are meant to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constexpr int x = 10;` implies `int const x = 10;`.

`constexpr int* p = &x;` implies `int* const p = &x;` - `p` is an unchangeable pointer to a changeable `int`.

In the generic form `constexpr T x = t;` implies `T const x = t;`. It doesn't change a pointee type.

C++ [does not allow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080727/12002570) to assign an address of a const to a pointer that points to a non const.

The proper solution in the global context:

```
constexpr int x = 10;
constexpr const int* p = &x;
```

The proper solution in a function local context:

```
int main() {
  static constexpr int x = 10;
  constexpr const int* p = &x;
}
```

`static` is not implied by `constexpr` and non static `constexpr` variable is just a usual runtime const variable.

Comment: This is wrong. Also the proper solution [won't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/s1frcWzcr) because it is ill-formed.

Comment: @user12002570 It compiles in the global context and should be static in a local context. I thought it was obvious.

Comment: *"I thought it was obvious..."* No it was not obvious at all. Especially when OP's code has the variables defined inside `main` and the answer didn't mention anything about static storage duration etc. The updated answer looks good. I've taken the downvote back.

Comment: @user12002570. Let us place the `static` case aside.  Could you please explain why `your` code works in the global context and not in the local context? Is it because inside `main` the address of `p` cannot be determined at compile time?

Comment: @ntos the address of the non static variable `p` is not constant. `constexpr` expression requires a constexpr initializer. See the dupe.

Comment: @273K. Thank you. The book I am reading is not good then. It never points out that `constexpr` makes a pointer constant, not the type it points to.

Comment: @ntos This is the same behavior as `int* p`, `const int* p`, `int* const p` and `const int* const p`, and should be demonstrated in the book.

Comment: @ntos I would recommend the best beginner book called "c++ primer by lippman 5th edition". If you search that term, you'll find pdf for the link .