# constexpr pointer towards constexpr array, is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, pointers, constexpr

I run into compilation error (https://godbolt.org/z/njv8xxsET),

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr char array[]={"my string"};
    // error: (const char*)(& array) is not a constant expression
    constexpr const char* ptr = array;
}
```

I thought using constexpr const and assgning other 'constexpr' is possible, but something is missing here.

and my **array **in the second line is highlighted as it contains error.

I have tried,

```
constexpr const char* ptr = array;
constexpr char* ptr = array;
constexpr char* const ptr = array;
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8MG3qfP3h). My guess is that you are declaring `array` inside a class, so it doesn't have static storage duration. But as posted, the code does work.

Comment: See the explanation given in the answer of the dupe: [`constexpr int* ptr =&i` compiles in msvc but not with clang and gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080727/12002570)

Answer (score 2):

Just because something is `constexpr` doesn't mean that its address (and thus a pointer to it) is also `constexpr`.
You can reproduce the problem more simply:

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr int x = 0;
    constexpr const int* p = &x; // error: &x is not a constant expression
}
```

GCC errors are very helpful:

> ```
> <source>:3:30: note: pointer to 'x' is not a constant expression
> <source>:2:19: note: address of non-static constexpr variable 'x'
>                      may differ on each invocation of the enclosing function;
>                      add 'static' to give it a constant address
>     2 |     constexpr int x = 0;
>       |                   ^
>       |                   static
> ```

`constexpr` just means that `array` or `x` are initialized using a constant expression.
However, they are objects just like any other variable.
A new `x` object is created every time the surrounding function is called, which obviously means that a pointer to it cannot be formed at compile-time.

The following code would fix this:

```cpp
int main() {
    static constexpr char array[]={"my string"};
    constexpr const char* ptr = array; // OK
}
```

A `static` object has static storage duration, meaning it only exists once per program.
This means its address is known at compile-time, and a pointer to it can be formed.